# Variations of the same word

Tags: verbs, nouns, morphology

Here is a question for you guys. Im trying to find a good website or whatever place  that can show me all forms of a specific word.

For example the word "transparent" has other morphologies like "transparency, transparentness"

Im quite aware these forms are noun, adjectival and sometimes adverbial.

So where or how can i find all forms of any word that may have it.

Comment: Try: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transparent

Comment: Every dictionary is different. M-W is one I like, especially for this reason. There may be better ones out there, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a request for resources is off-topic.